# Java- Calendar timezone not getting applied

Tags: java

I have a date/time which will in "GMT +5:30" and I want to change it to "GMT +0.00" in other words I want 5:30 hours less than what I Will get from screen. I tried following code but it's not working.

```
Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-0.00"));
dt.setTimeInMillis(inputDate.getTime());
dt.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
inputDate = dt.getTime();
```

Comment: A date doesn't have a timezone.

Comment: Could you paste the values of inputData and the final value of dt?

Comment: Actually we are getting date from screen through "DatePicker" which is an GWT component and this picker has timezone of "GMT" and that will directly converts available date to "Date" object. In turn we will get date/time which will be in GMT.

Comment: In the question, you've mentioned that "it's not working". Could you be more specific? What's the output you're getting and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: I want to search based on date given by user. Suppose I have record in DB with Date say "02/06/2014 10:00:00 AM" and I will give Date to search as "02/06/2014 10:00:00 AM" it WOnt search. But If I give 5:30 hours less than that means around "02/06/2014 04:30:00 AM" then record will be searched. In SQL developer If I check that record it will show me date as "02/06/2014 10:00:00 AM" only

Answer (score 0):

This will set time zone for the JVM.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

> This will reflect in the entire Application so you must be careful
>   while using it.

Calendar in Java use the UTC as the default timezone. You can get change the timezone for calendar object using this

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
  cal.setTimeZone(tz);
```

This will only change the timezone of that particular object.

Comment: Changing the default time zone of the JVM is a drastic approach. It affects all code running in all threads of that JVM.

Comment: @BasilBourque I believe it depends on the place you use it. Like in a server, its the best practice to have some common time like GMT. But for single time use, i won't insist to use the same. Thanks for notifying me. Added the note.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will give you time of GMT 0

```
  calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Copenhagen"));
    System.out.println("CPH: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("CPH: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that your code is fine. You may check it by printing dt.getTimeZone before printing time. The catch is that dt.toString will again convert the time to the machine's timezone on which your code is running. It happens because .toString() is implemented in such a way. Check the APIs and implement it in a way like

```
Date inputDate = new Date();
    Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance();
    dt.setTimeInMillis(inputDate.getTime());
    dt.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    inputDate = dt.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-0.00"));
    System.out.println(format.format(dt.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thank You! I will try This. SimpleDateFormat  is of type "java.text" or "com.ibm.icu" ?